# Xml Serialization/Deserialization of Class in Swift

Tags: ios, xml, swift, serialization

As being new to [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/)

i don't know how to serialize a class into xml

```
Class Employee
{
    var mName : String = ""
    var Name : String
        {
        get
        {
            return mName
        }
        set
        {
            mName = newValue
        }
    }
    var mDesingation : String = ""
    var Desingation: String
        {
        get
        {
            return mDesingation 
        }
        set
        {
            mDesingation = newValue
        }
    }

}
```

I have searched a lot but haven't come across any XML Serialization Engine for Swift.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need to serialize it into XML (sending to server maybe?), or do you simply want to save it to disk so you can load it again? If so, I will provide you with the way how to do it

Comment: Its because we have a windows 8 app where we need to send the xml file through IOS.we can't use Json..

Comment: Yes yes exactly that would be great :)

Answer (score 5):

**XML Serialization**

For XML serialization, I suggest you use following library:

https://github.com/skjolber/xswi

As the usage is quite easy but well documented, I won't copy it here, instead you can just use examples that they provide. Since your class is very easy, it is sufficient solution. AFAIK there is no library that provides automatic serialization, because it is not used on iOS. Core data provide you with option to serialize as XML, but that is highly problematic and mostly not usable for what you want.

**NSCoding / NSKeyedArchiver**

If you need to just store the class on the disk and load it again, there is better option, and that is to use `NSKeyedArchiver`  / `NSCoding` protocol. Again, [there is great article](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/) about how to use it with extensive examples, so just the basics:

- You extend your class so it conforms to `NSCoding` protocol
- You write implementation of two methods - `encodeWithCoder:` and `initWithDecoder:`
- You use `NSKeyedArchiver` to archive your class
- You write `NSData` that you save to disk (and vice versa)

Hope it helps!